# MySQL subquery or join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I have to migrate Date from one table to another.

This is the source Table. For every testid there are 2 channels with 3 rows per channel.

```
id  value1  value2  testid  channel
1   123     567     789     asd
2   125     587     789     asd
3   126     596     789     asd
4   569     12      789     qwe
5   567     15      789     qwe
6   563     19      789     qwe
7   12      877     963     asd
8   23      765     963     asd
9   34      676     963     asd
10  987     23      963     qwe
11  876     34      963     qwe
12  678     12      963     qwe
```

into this

```
id  value1_asd  value2_asd  value1_qwe  value_2_qwe test_id
1     124.6       583.3      566.3        15.3       789
```

Can this be done in one query? I can do it in several but that takes ages in my real table. I have more than 4 million entries.

Comment: I don't see queries or tables here. If your question is about MySQL then strip the HTML, post only the data. Check also this page: [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i found a solution...

```
INSERT INTO table2 (value1_asd,value2_asd,value1_qwe,value_2_qwe,test_id) SELECT T1.v1,T1.v2,T2.v1,T2.v2,T2.testid
FROM (SELECT AVG(`value1`) as v1, AVG(`value2`) as v2, `channel`, `testid` FROM table1 WHERE `channel` = 'asd' GROUP BY `testid`) AS T1,
(SELECT AVG(`value1`) as v1, AVG(`value2`) as v2, `channel`, `testid` FROM table1 WHERE `channel` = 'qwe' GROUP BY `testid`) AS T2
WHERE T1.testid = T2.testid
GROUP BY T2.testid
```

thanks for your solution it gave me the right idea.
SG

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to make it easy, keep `id` of the second table auto increment.

Then you can run this query,

```
INSERT INTO table2 (value1_asd,value2_asd,value1_qwe,value_2_qwe,test_id) SELECT AVG(T1.value1),AVG(T1.value2),AVG(T2.value1),AVG(T2.value2),AVG(T3.testid)
FROM Table1 AS T1,Table1 AS T2,Table1 AS T3 
WHERE T1.channel='asd' AND T2.channel='qwe';
```

The `select` will select the average of the fields. Since we have 3 scenarios here

> 1)channel='asd'
>   2)channel='qwe'
>   3)testid

We are treating the same table as 3 different tables(using Alias).
The values selected in the `select` will be inserted into the second table table2.

Hope this helped.

Comment: this works if there is only one set of data in the table. But with a second set of data with another testid the result is a mess...

Comment: So you mean you will be needing the average of testid based on the channel too. So are you expecting two records in the second table ?